# Python Selenium - Finding a dynamic word on a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web

I'm trying to check if a word is or is not on a webpage by using Selenium on Python.
The problem is the word is dynamic: it will only appear after I do some action (in my case, selecting an option on a dropdown list).

I've tried to use

```
"text" is in driver.page_source"
```

But it doesn't work: it will not detect my dynamic text (even though it detects other static texts).

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please check if you get the page source *after* doing actions which will make the text appear:
`
do_some_actions()
"text" in driver.page_source
`
. If you are sure you do everything right, please, provide an example (or link)

Comment: Usually the text appears or disappears is controlled by a webpage element. Try using implicit (`driver.implicitly_wait`) or explicit (`WebDriverWait`) wait to poll the element. See [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: @NChechulin @FearlessSniper

Thank you for your help. That's actually what my code looks like : 

`driver.get('http//exemple.com')`

`driver.implictly_wait(10)`

`# code to make the text appear`

`driver.implictly_wait(10)`

`if "text" is in driver.page_source:`

`print('Exist')`

`else:`

`print('Not exist')`

Comment: what is the tag that include text?

Comment: @Rob Can you try mimicking user behavior like selecting the dropdown menu, then try to retrieve the text? Sometimes on-page javascripts removes the element from page instead of setting it to invisible.

Comment: <td class="table_cell__3IMdZ">AC:1000000012</td> The text is the AC:10000XXX

Comment: When I do it myself (dropping down the menu to select an option and selecting an option), I see the text appearing. What do you mean trying to retrieve the text?